# Serializable to Json saving Memory leaks

Tags: java, json, string, file, gson

I recently changed it so that my project saves and loads a Player with json/gson String.

However, whenever I attempt to save, I get a

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
```

I removed the implementation of Serializable on the Player, however, there still may be some fields that are serializable that are being saved in the player.

Is this the issue? That I still have some serializable items attributed to the player that is being saved with json/gson?

Or is it something else?

Edit: It does not even save the player, it gives the out of memory error before saving the file

Comment: The issue is that you have not enough memory.

Comment: Unless the json parser you use is really quirky, `Serializable` shouldn't have much to do with that. Chances are you have simply insufficient memory, or you're serializing too large objects

Comment: you can use `jconsole` or other tools to analysis your memory usage.

Comment: Does serializable object saving allow for larger objects than json saving or something? I am not trying to save a very very large object though.

Comment: I think you have bidirectional relationships that are being infinite looped. Check if you have reverse references from the object you are serializing. e.g. If Player refers to an object called Team and Team has a collection of Players, then the serialization will infinitely loop.

Comment: @horatius Saving and loading was working fine before I switched to Json though.

Comment: That's exactly how it works for circular references. You only encounter the loops when you serialize the object graph.